# Argument of type 'Observable<number[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<ProjectObject[]>'. want to create mock service

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, rxjs, observable

This is my testing file i want to create mock service for unit testings the observable is not returning the fake value. Please help me to solve this issue and also please explain me what's wrong in my code.

**all-projects.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ProjectsService } from './../../../../services/projects/projects.service';
import { AllProjectsComponent } from './all-projects.component';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


describe('allprojectComponent', () => {

    let component: AllProjectsComponent;
    let service: ProjectsService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        service = new ProjectsService(null, null);
        component = new AllProjectsComponent(service);
    });

    it('should set projects property with the items returned from the server', () => {
        spyOn(service,'getAllprojects').and.returnValue(Observable.from([[1,2,4]]))
    })
});
```

this is my service file.

**project.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpBackend, HttpParams  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from './../../../../environments/environment';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectsService {
  public API = environment.apiUrl;
  public newHttp;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient, private handler: HttpBackend ) {

    this.newHttp = new HttpClient(this.handler);

  }

  getAllprojects(): Observable<ProjectObject[]> {
    return this.http.get<ProjectObject[]>(this.API + '/projects');
  }
```

This file is my project model.
**project.model.ts**

```
export interface Docs {
    fileType : string,
    extension: string
}



export interface Project {
    projectType: string;
    status: string;
    totalBids: number;
    _id: string;
    clientID: string;
    projectName: string;
    licenseType: string;
    location: string;
    description: string;
    duration: number;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    __v: number;
}

export interface OpenFaq {
    _id: string;
    engineerID: string;
    question: string;
}

export interface ProjectObject {
    project: Project;
    openFaq: OpenFaq[];
    closedFaq: any[];
    doc: any[];
}
```

Comment: Where do you `subscribe` to `getAllprojects`?

Comment: Beside `subscribe` place note that your spy return array of array with numbers but your http call should return `Observable<ProjectObject[]>`

Comment: this.projectsService.getAllprojects().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.projects = data; });

Comment: this is how i'm subscribing my http call

Comment: This is my json response.

Comment: [
   {
      "projectType":"public",
      "status":"open",
      "totalBids":0,
      "_id":"5e9ea8331fc632001772b45f",
      "clientID":"5e95bc033fd3a8001763a558",
      "projectName":"car manufacture",
      "licenseType":"mechanical",
      "location":"wuhan",
      "description":"specimen book.",
      "duration":23,
      "createdAt":"2020-04-21T08:00:51.885Z",
      "updatedAt":"2020-04-21T08:00:51.885Z",
      "__v":0
   }
]

Comment: please tell me how to return <ProjectObject[]> value i'm new to angular and observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have basic set up for test:

```
  it('should set projects property with the items returned from the server', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'getAllprojects').and.returnValue(of([
      // Here you can provide object with full properties from ProjectObject or minimum just to make test pass
      {} as ProjectObject,
      {} as ProjectObject,
      {} as ProjectObject,
    ]));

    component.methodName(); // trigger method that will subscribe to service

    // check whatever you want which is related with fetching data from that service
  });
```